# Is it possible to call Matlab from QtCreator?

Tags: c++, matlab, qt-creator, mex

I am doing image analysis using C++ in the QtCreator environment. In order to build a learning model, I want to use the TreeBagger class from MATLAB, which is really powerful. Can I call MATLAB from QtCreator, give it some parameters, and get back the classification error? Can I do this without using mex files?

Comment: Have you researched opening up matlab.exe and working w/ it through something like QProcess?

Comment: @dans3itz No, can you tell me more about it?

Answer (score 2):

From QProcess's Synchronous Process API example:

```
 QProcess gzip;
 gzip.start("gzip", QStringList() << "-c");
 if (!gzip.waitForStarted())
     return false;

 gzip.write("Qt rocks!");
 gzip.closeWriteChannel();

 if (!gzip.waitForFinished())
     return false;

 QByteArray result = gzip.readAll();
```

The concept to from this example is the process of being able to execute matlab w/ whatever settings that would be preferable and begin writing a script to it immediately. After the write; you can close the channel, wait for response, then read the results from matlab. Uunfortunately, I'm not experienced w/ it to provide a more direct example, but this is the concept for the most case. Please research the documentation for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has an "engine" interface described [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html) to let standalone programs call matlab functions. It has the advantage that you can call `engPutVariable`and `engGetVariable` to transfer your data in binary format (I think it works by using shared memory between your process and matlab, but I'm not sure on this), so you don't have to convert your data to ascii and parse the result from ascii.

For c++ you might want to write a wrapper class for RAII or have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4216/MATLAB-Engine-API, where this has already been done.